# How to get gas price in Solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price

I'm on the most recent version on solidity.

"tx.gas" and "tx.gasprice" both dont work. They error with "Member "gas" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in tx".

How do I get the gasPrice in the contract?

Answer (score 2):

Solidity does not yet implement a `gasprice` high level function. If you need the gas price, you need to use assembly at least to get the value:

```js
assembly {
            gasPrice := gasprice()
        }
```

For example, take a look at the following function that uses assembly to set the gas price to a local variable and return it from a function:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Contract {

    function getGasPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 gasPrice;
        assembly {
            gasPrice := gasprice()
        }
        return gasPrice;
    }

}
```